# Проблема в точности подсчета значения

Tags: алгоритм

Задача в том, чтоб найти скорость сближения часовой и минутной стрелки и сколько раз они окажутся на одной прямой. Если считать в градусах, то получается:
У минутной 6 градусов в минуту.
У часовой 0.5 градуса в минуту.
Тогда их скорость сближения 5.5 градуса.
Так как они оказываются на одной прямой, то 180/5.5 получается число 32.7272(72) минуты на то, чтоб они оказались на одной прямой.
Есть ли другие методы поиска значения? Так как при больший числах программа начинает лажать.

Comment: @Drakonoved 360 градусов / 60 минут?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev минутная стрелка делает полный оборот в минуту, т.е. 360 градусов / 1 минута.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Это секундная за 1 минуту. А минутная за 1 час=60 минут.

Comment: @becouse Точно, затупил :)

Comment: Так вам надо найти точные промежутки или количество раз, сколько они встретятся?

Answer (score 0):

Скорость минутной 6 градусов/минута, скорость часовой 0.5 градуса/минута

угол на который повернется минутная стрелка за t минут 6t, угол на который повернется часовая стрелка за t минут 0.5t.

Для того чтобы они лежали на одной прямой есть 2 случая.

1. Угол=0 6t-0.5t=0, t=0 или 6t-0.5t=360 11t/2=360, t=720/11 минут
2. Угол=180 6t-0.5t=180 11t/2=180, t=360/11 минут

Получаем каждые 0, 360/11, 720/11 минут стрелки находятся на одной прямой.

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. Стрелки движутся непрерывно